# Javascript invalid function? what I am missing?

Tags: javascript

I used textwrangler to write my codes to better show my codes and progression. On the comment section of my codes, I wrote my concern and the purpose of my codes.

```
var pets = ["pet1", "pet2", "pet3"]

function displayPets() {
    console.log("my pets:", pets);
}

// addPets() will name all new pets "new pets" ie ("pet1", "pet2", "pet3", "new pets"....)

function addPets() {
    pets.push("new pet");
    displayPets();
}

/ try different method using the parameter

function addPets(petName) {
    pets.push("petName");
    displayPets();
}

// pets.push isn't not a function
addPets(brutus)
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There are no overloaded functions in JavaScript.

Comment: post some way we can copy,

Comment: pets.push isn't a function. that's the error I keep getting.

Comment: It doesn't look like this code would throw that error.

Comment: @JohnDavis Based on current information, your code is working fine. **[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/y5Lrtm4k/)** Can you paste exact code which is throwing error?

Answer (score 0):

Will in the different and the first function you are using the same name and you may see another error(not basically error its just a bug) that you can not take the input from the perimeter that is because you are push an string not the variable in the different method and when you are calling the different function you are not putting an string that will also cause an error, If you are not understand hoping the below code can help

```js
var pets = ["pet1", "pet2", "pet3"]

function displayPets() {
    console.log("my pets:", pets);
}

// addPets() will name all new pets "new pets" ie ("pet1", "pet2", "pet3", "new pets"....)

function addPets() {
    pets.push("new pehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062303/javascript-invalid-function-what-i-am-missing#t");
    displayPets();
}

// try different method using the parameter

function addPetsDifferentMethod(petName) {
    pets.push(petName);
    displayPets();
}

// pets.push isn't not a function
addPetsDifferentMethod("brutes")
```

Answer (score -2):

There are no overload functions in JS. The last one will alway be called. we have to write the function defeniton to act like Overloaded function.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfbuqt3n/)

```
 function addPets(petName){
       if(petName){ // if petname is present
        pets.push(petName)
      }
      else{
      pets.push("newPet");
      }
      displayPets();
    }
```

Comment: I believe you're covering a different subject.

Comment: @JinsPeter Let me charify. JS does not have overloading. It takes last value. But that should and is working fine. So if this is the exact code, there is NO issue to solve. If issue is coming, its not from here and we will need more context. But overloading will NEVER throw `pets.push is not a function`. That will happen if `pets` is not an array. So question is unclear and any solution based on current state will not be a concrete solution.

Comment: @Rajesh THE OP did not say pets.push throw error when i answered. He posted that afterwards

Comment: @JinsPeter The error was there the whole time and your answer doesn't address it. The error was in the very revision of the post.